# Update, please, about ELL graduating from Beta

Tags: discussion, beta

See [What's keeping the site in beta, and what can we do to get it graduated?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/whats-keeping-the-site-in-beta-and-what-can-we-do-to-get-it-graduated)

I'd appreciate an update, and an explanation of what the hold-up is.

I have searched on SE, to no avail.

Answer (score 7):

The site has graduated... sort of.

There's nothing "holding it up".

The [Mod Elections](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1) that are currently occurring are the first step in the updated graduation model.

Up until recently, SE has been limited to graduating sites on the schedule of the site design team. Unfortunately, they're a bit backlogged and [have several sites "in queue"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247739/site-launched-who-is-next) (note that this link is from January, so ELL has been approved for graduation since that time).

As of August 2015, a [new site graduation process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263905/design-independent-graduation-is-on-for-early-september) has been created, separating the design elements from the graduation process:

> Phase 1
>
> *The Community Team announces that a site is cleared for graduation. Without delay...*
>
> - the beta label is removed
> - elections are held
> - migration paths are set up
> - community ads are run
>
> Phase 2
>
> *Then, as it becomes available:*
>
> - the site gets their custom design.
> - privilege thresholds are increased to graduated site levels

As far as I know, SE has not yet created a generic "graduated" site skin, though it may remain the same for a while, simply without the Beta logo.

As it specifically relates to ELL, you can see the following comments:

> Curious... how does this affect sites like Anime, which is currently going through elections but don't have a site design? You say it's starting in September but... is some of it already rolling out a bit right now? –  Catija [Aug 19 at 16:48](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263905/design-independent-graduation-is-on-for-early-september#comment858787_263905)
>
> @Catija: Yes... sort of. One of the reasons we started working on design-independent graduation was the growing list of sites that were cleared to graduate and whose moderator teams needed some extra support. Rather than select more pro-tem moderators while they waited for designs, it seemed best to give them elections ASAP. –  [abby hairboat♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/165581/abby-hairboat) Aug 19 at 16:50
>
> @abbyhairboat Is ELL on that list? –  Catija Aug 19 at 17:01
>
> @Catija Yes, ELL will be part of the batch that starts the process next month (after we work out the kinks on Magento). –  abby hairboat♦ Aug 19 at 17:06

In reaction to this question and the comments on this answer, I asked for any guidance about the removal of the Beta logo for sites and the response I received is [below](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263905/design-independent-graduation-is-on-for-early-september?noredirect=1#comment862577_263905):

> I know that next week is the week this is supposed to happen but do you have any info for us about when/whether the "beta" part of the logo is going to be dropped or if design-independent sites will get a different design than the currently-beta sites? If you like, I'm happy to address this in a question, not certain if it's been addressed yet, though. –  Catija
>
> Hey @Catija the "beta" label will be dropped on newly graduated sites, specifically, after their election has wrapped up. We are not currently slated to give newly graduated sites an interim design because it would have caused delays in getting this thing underway, but I feel it may be a good future adjustment. If you a) think there's widespread confusion about when/whether the "beta" label is being dropped or b) would like to add another voice in support of an interim design, I encourage you to ask a new question. Ana♦

So, it seems that we should have the Beta logo gone within the week.

For more information, see the following MSE topics on the subject:

- [Design-Independent Graduation is on for early September!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263905/design-independent-graduation-is-on-for-early-september)
- [Feedback Requested: Design-Independent Graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754/feedback-requested-design-independent-graduation)
- [Graduation, site closure, and a clearer outlook on the health of SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites)
- [Can Beta sites slated for graduation get full-site abilities without site design upgrade?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257317/can-beta-sites-slated-for-graduation-get-full-site-abilities-without-site-design)

Comment: Aparente's point is surely *wHY IS THE BETA LOGO STILL ON THE SITE?*. There does seem to be some kind of hold up on that affront (sic!).

Comment: @Arau it probably will get removed as soon as the election results are out.

Comment: @Araucaria I'm not certain where you're getting that interpretation from... I **do** mention in my answer that, as of now, there is no generic non-beta site design... so, clearly we're waiting on that. I'm not versed enough in web design to know whether it's possible to simply remove the "beta" word and change nothing else... and, technically, since SE hasn't officially told us that we've graduated, we haven't graduated.

Comment: I'd imagine that no-one will feel that we've graduated whilst "beta"  is on the site. So I might be getting that from there ... ?

Comment: Since the "logo" right now is just  `<a href="/">
                    English Language Learners
                        <span class="beta-title">beta</span>
                </a>`, all they'd have to do is remove the `<span class="beta-title">beta</span>`. Presumably that will happen whenever "graduation" is official.

Comment: @AaronBrown Yes... most likely, though I wouldn't complain if they made the theme a different color in addition to removing the label. We'll probably find out next week, which is the timeline that is mentioned in the Meta SE announcement I've linked to.

Answer (score 2):

It graduated out fully today, with graduated privilege rep requirements...

**Edit: Disregard; it was a bug!**

Comment: ... But still no design.

Comment: How much did the (most important) reputation requirements change? For example, new user commenting, new user suggesting edits, edits not requiring approval, inline tag editing?

Comment: @Jasper You need a few thousand reputation to review everything now. Also on beta you used to be able to close vote at 750 rep, and edit questions/answers freely at 1000.

Comment: This was a bug. Specifically, entirely my fault - I renamed the setting that overrides normal privilege thresholds for graduated sites and keeps them at the public beta levels. I forgot that the setting values don't get moved over in the rename, so the thresholds jumped up. I restored the correct settings here and on other sites that have been graduated under the new design-independent system, so everything should be back to normal. Sorry!

Comment: @AnnaLear: Fair cop! I'm glad to have 2k tools back for a while longer before I have to let them go again....

Answer (score 2):

How the reputation requirements for some key [privileges](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) will [change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared):

- [Inline tag editing.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)   Again 2,000.  Will be 10,000.  This privilege makes it much easier to burninate tags.
- [Vote to close questions.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions)  Again 500.  Will be 3,000.
- Vote to re-open questions.  Ditto.
- [Automatically approved edits](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) to questions and answers.  Again 1,000.  Will be 2,000.  This privilege makes it practical to burninate tags.

Some reputation requirements stay the same.  For example:

- [Vote down.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down)  Still 125.
- [Comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) on other people's posts.  Still 50.
- [Vote up.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up)  Still 15.

Comment: Did you read Anna's statement saying it was an accident?

Comment: @Nihilist_Frost -- Anna wrote her comment while I was writing my answer, so I did not see her comment until after I answered.  Fortunately, I have downloaded copies of the two different versions of http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges .

Comment: There's a full list of privileges compared by site state [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared).